# How to copy element from one array to other element of array using pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am attempting to copy the elements of one dynamically-allocated array (`addVec`) into another (`array`) in memory, after passing a pointer to the array from `main` to a function (`changeArray`) that assigns values to `addVec`.

My approach thus far:

1. Dynamically allocate an array (`array`) in `main`
2. Dynamically allocate another array (`addVec`) in `changeArray()`
3. Pass the pointer of this dynamically-allocated array and receive it in changeArray.

However, I am not sure how to correctly carry out steps 3 and 4, namely copying the elements of `addVec` into `array`.

```c
void changeArray(double** vec1)
{
    double* addVec = (double*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double num = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        *(addVec + i) = num;
        num = num + 1;
    }

    printf("Printing out addVec: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.1f ", *(addVec + i));
    }

    printf("\nNow we want to copy elements from addVec to vec1.\n");
    // Step 4
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        **(vec1 + i) = *(addVec + i);
    }

    free(addVec);
}

int main()
{
    double* array = (double*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(double));
    double num = 11.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        *(array + i) = num;
        num = num + 1;
    }
    printf("The address of array is: %x \n", array);

    changeArray(&array);

    printf("The array is now: 1, 2, 3... \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.1f ", *(array + i));
    }

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `**(vec1 + i)` you're incrementing the wrong pointer. Instead do `*(*vec1 + 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `changeArray` declared like

```
void changeArray(double** vec1)
```

does not make sense. For example the pointer `array` is passed to the function by reference through a pointer to it

```
changeArray(&array);
```

but the passed pointer is not changed within the function. The function declaration is senseless. You could declare the function at least like

```
void changeArray(double *vec1)
```

and call it like

```
changeArray(array);
```

To change elements of the array pointed to by the pointer `array` there is no any sense to allocate dynamically one more array.

Nevertheless in any case the function has a bug in this `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    **(vec1 + i) = *(addVec + i);
}
```

Instead you need to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    *(*vec1 + i) = *(addVec + i);
}
```

That is at first you need to dereference the pointer `vec1` to get an access to the original pointer `array` and then apply the pointer arithmetic the same ways as on the right side of the assignment statement.

If you wanted to create dynamically a new array and reassign the passed pointer with the address of the newly dynamically allocated array then the function could look for example like

```
int changeArray( double **vec1 )
{
    double *addVec = calloc( SIZE, sizeof( double ) );
    int success = addVec != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        free( *vec1 );

        double num = 1.0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i )
        {
            *( addVec + i ) = num;
            ++num;
        }

        printf("Printing out addVec: \n");
        for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i )
        {
            printf( "%.1f ", *( addVec + i ) );
        }

        printf("\nNow we want to copy elements from addVec to vec1.\n");

        *vec1 = addVec;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And in this case it is called like `changeArray( &array )`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I got so confused with the knowledge of 'pointer can modify the data that it is pointing at' and I did not really think in deep for the 'array is already a pointer'. Thank you so much :)

Comment: What I wanted to test is that just copying the element from function and see if the array from main has changed ;) so I think I got very confused with my own statement. Is there a way to copy the whole element from the array to other array? –

Comment: It really helped lots for my pointer understanding! Thank you so much!